# (Help)How to drop specific text rows in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want simple coding.
The number of rows and columns can vary
I want to drop rows with NG text
In many cases, there are even 100 columns.

```
#  file open
input_path = pd.read_csv(output_path4, skipinitialspace = True)

#  text "NG??" columns Drop
No1= input_path[~input_path['NO.1'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No2= No1[~No1['NO.2'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No3= No2[~No2['NO.3'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No4= No3[~No3['NO.4'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No5= No4[~No4['NO.5'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No6= No5[~No5['NO.6'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No7= No6[~No6['NO.7'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No8= No7[~No7['NO.8'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No9= No8[~No8['NO.9'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No10= No9[~No9['NO.10'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No11= No10[~No10['NO.11'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No12= No11[~No11['NO.12'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No13= No12[~No12['NO.13'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No14= No13[~No13['NO.14'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No15= No14[~No14['NO.15'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No16= No15[~No15['NO.16'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No17= No16[~No16['NO.17'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No18= No17[~No17['NO.18'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No19= No18[~No18['NO.19'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No20= No19[~No19['NO.20'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]
No21= No20[~No20['NO.21'].str.contains("NG", na=False, case=False)]

#  "Unnamed?" Rows Drop
No22 = No21.loc[:, ~No21.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]

#  " " columns Drop
No23=No22.dropna()

#  file save
No23.to_csv( output_path, index=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, try:

```
output = input_path[~input_path.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains("NG")).any(axis=1)]
```